# Android Studio Deletes Java Files

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm running Android Studio 1.1.0 on osx 10.9.2.  Android Studio has started deleting my project's java files. I've imported several Eclipse projects via the import wizard and have put them into new folders.

I've then worked on these projects for a day or two and come back to discover that the project folders are mostly empty. This has now happened with ~7 projects. The damaged project folders now contain only:

1. Project.iml
2. .idea
3. .DS_Store

I've not had other file loss issues on this machine. I have been closing the IDE with several projects open. I'm wondering if this may be killing my projects.

Comment: Maybe you're putting files in the wrong folder. Can you post your directory structure and where you are attempting to put files?

Comment: Are you sure the files are actually deleted from disk? In some cases (for example, if your project does not have any modules), Android Studio will not show the entire contents of the project directory in Project view, even though the files are still there.

Comment: As a test,I created a 'HellWorld' project. I then exited AS, navigated to the project folder, deleted all of the files except for Project.iml, .idea, .DS_Store. I then restarted AS. The behavior I see for this project is identical to my damaged projects. AS *is* deleting files.